# Rails : Check if field is blank on submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In a rails application i've a search field that i must control (on the submit action) if it's blank. 
This one is not connected to a table for register some data:

```
 <%= form_tag products_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]%>
  <%= submit_tag "Ricerca" %>   
 <% end %>
```

i've tried define an action in my controller for check the value of the parameters that i pass:

```
if !(params[:search].present?)
  redirect_to root_path, error: 'Insert a research key'
else
  @count = Product.search(params[:search]).count

  if @count == 0
    redirect_to root_path, error: 'No data found for your search'
  else
    @products = Product.search(params[:search])
  end
end
```

Any idea for the validation of my field throught Rails?

Comment: your code seems ok!. What is the problem

Answer (score 3):

You can use HTML5 validations for the client side (you should still do a server side check):

```
<%= form_tag products_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], required: true %>
  <%= submit_tag "Ricerca" %>   
<% end %>
```

`:required => true` will require that there be something in the search field.

Answer (score 3):

Use ActiveModel for a tableless model with validations.

the model:

```
class ExampleSearch
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :input

  validates_presence_of :input
  validates_length_of :input, :maximum => 500

end
```

and your form:

```
<%= form_for ExampleSearch.new(), :url=>posts_path, :method=>:get, :validate=>true do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :input %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :input, required: true %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Search" %></p>
<% end %>
```

For good user experience use `gem 'client_side_validations'`

Info on ActiveModel:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model

Answer (score 2):

You can validate both server side, and client side. You're going to want server side always, as the url can be accessed without using the form, and you need a way to handle that. Client side will make the user experience better, as they don't need to reload the page for feedback.

For server side it's as easy as `if params[:search].blank?` this will check for both `= nil` and `= ""`.

For client side there are 2 main ways. Javascript and HTML 5. With HTML 5 you can add `:required => true` to your form elements, and that's all you need. 
Using javascript, or in this case JQuery it could work something like this

```
$('form').submit(function() {  //When a form is submitted...
  $('input').each(function() { //Check each input...
    if ($(this).val() == "") { //To see if it is empty...
      alert("Missing field");//Say that it is
      return false;            //Don't submit the form
    }
  });
  return;                      //If we made it this far, all is well, submit the form
});
```

Comment: I used :required=>true on Firefox and it's great, but it is not working on google chrome.